# List all ALBs & ELBs

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I am looking cmdlet to list all ALB & ELB in my account, result should only list Name, not any other parts.
So example, if I can get it as below, it would be great:

ALB-11
ALB-2222
ALB111
ALB333

Answer (score 5):

Use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which has a [describe-load-balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elb/describe-load-balancers.html) command.

For example:

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers --query LoadBalancerDescriptions[*].LoadBalancerName --output text

aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --query LoadBalancers[*].LoadBalancerName --output text
```

Comment: And for application load balancers: `aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --query 'LoadBalancers[*].LoadBalancerName' --output text`

Comment: Can it list ALB and ELB together?

Comment: How can I list ELB + SSLCertificateId ?

Comment: Ah! I think you need to use `aws elbv2` (see above) for ALBs. I presume NLBs, too. You'll have to experiment.

Comment: It appears that certificates are retrieved via [describe-listener-certificates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/describe-listener-certificates.html)

Comment: Do you know how can I retrieve Tags?

Comment: See the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/index.html

Comment: I did, but didn't find to retrieve all tags instead of just 1.